# How to do use ng2-file-upload with rest service

Tags: angular, rest, xmlhttprequest, multer, ng2-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload with rest api backend , no multer 
Want to know , if ng2-file-upload is doing http post internally or we need to create a service to do http post

I have taken code from demo
https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

```
 public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL,maxFileSize: 
 maxFileSize,autoUpload:true});
 public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
 public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

 public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
   this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
 }

 public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
   this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
 }
}
```

Comment: depend if your upload is instantiated with option autoUpload to true or false. If false you will have to trigger the uploadItem function ( on uploader )

Comment: @PierreMallet upload is instantiated with autoUpload true but no http post request  is generated

Comment: @PierreMallet only request with OPTIONS Method is coming

Comment: How to call uploadItem?

Comment: can you add the headers on the OPTIONS response to your answer, it seems like you have a CORS error here (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Have you an error in your console ?

Comment: @PierreMallet Yes it worked